# Mock of Ext JS 4 documentation

Tags: extjs4, extjs

I have been researching for various type of documentation options for our products. I thought it would be cool to have [Ext JS 4 Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide) type of look&feel rather than Twiki.

But I am having tough time to understand the current docs page in Ext JS 4.0.7. Each and every directory has README.js & README.md.  If I am not wrong, I have to create my custom documentation in README.md, but I am failing to understand how that would be converted into README.js.

Could someone let me know how to `.md` file can be converted into `.js`?

Answer (score 2):

They are using a self made tool, which is called [JSDuck](https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck)

I guess you need to run it over your .md files and it will generate the .js files for you.

Comment: You need to have a certain amount of rep points before you can comment. See the faq.

Comment: Thanks Demnogonis. I have downloaded jsduck-3.2.1.exe, but I could not figure out a way to convert a .md file. Could you let me know the command to do the same.

Comment: No, I can't. :( I just found it in the bottom right corner of the normal [ExtJS Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#) and never used it by myself. You should take a look at the rest of the Github project. Below the files list is a readme, which gives an introduction to JSDuck and links with more detailed material. I think everything you need is in there. :)

Answer (score 1):

JsDuck is the way to go. I'm using it to build some custom documentation.

To get the guides:

1. just create a json file. I usually call it guides.json and write out the structure. It is well defined in the link below.
2. Create a folder in the same location as the guides file and in it:

   - create a folder for each entry in  the json. (each entry  has a name field and this should be the name  of the folder)
   - Create the file readme.md
   - Add an icon to it. It should be names icon-lg.png
3. When using jsduck from the command line, add the following to the arguments:

   ```
   --guides=[the path to your guides.json file]
   ```

More information can be found here:
https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck/wiki/Advanced-Usage (go to the guides section)

Also, to  get more information on the commandline parameters, use the command

```
jsduck-3.2.1 --help=full
```

Hope this works for you.